# How can I print double quotes ("") in java where parameters are used to print the value?

Tags: java

Below is my code:

```
String str = "something";
char ch = 'e';
int noOfOcc = 1;
System.out.println("No of occurrences of '"+ch+"' in "+str+" is "+noOfOcc);
```

Expected output should be as follows:

```
No of occurrences of 'e' in "something" is 1
```

How can I print that *something* in double quotes? I need solution for this case where we are using variables in System.out.println();. and I need the value of that variable in double quotes.

Comment: Use a backslash to escape your double quotes

Answer (score 2):

Escape it using `\"` so that the complier knows not to treat your `"` as something to demarcate the start or end of a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
System.out.println("No of occurrences of '"+ch+"' in \""+str+"\" is "+noOfOcc);
```

Backward slash acts as escape sequence to print double quotes.
Compiler don't interpret the character after slash symbol.

Comment: System.out.println("No of occurances of '"+ch+"' in \""+str+"\""+" is "+noOfOcc);

Thanks. This worked for me.